# How to put <a> at the end of <li> line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something like file tree. The structure is like that:

```
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="directory">
    <a href="">dir1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="file"><a href="">file1</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">file2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="file"><a href="">file3</a></li>
  <li class="file"><a href="">file4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also used some CSS:

```
ul.tree li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.tree a {
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 2px;
}
.tree li.directory { 
  background: url(/images/directory.png) left top no-repeat; 
}
.tree li.file { 
  background: url(/images/file.png) left top no-repeat; 
}
```

It gives me fine effect - I need tree more digged in with every inner directory, and `<a>` with width from given position to the end of line (tree area has specified width, but it can be scrolled if path or filename is longer then tree area's width). Well, it was ok until now. 
But now I have to change it a little and put a "delete" option at the end of line. With it, `<a>` should end before "delete", so

```
display:block;
```

is probably no longer correct. I tried

```
display: inline-block;
```

but then, the `<a>` area ends with the end of file name - and I still need it until the "delete", which should be at the end of line. 
The new structure should be like this:

```
<ul class="tree">
  <li class="directory">
    <a href="">dir1</a><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="file"><a href="">file1</a><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
      <li class="file"><a href="">file2</a><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="file"><a href="">file3</a><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
  <li class="file"><a href="">file4</a><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know what styles or what else should I use to do it the way, I want to. So, could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to read your post multiple times to try to get what you were looking for. If I'm reading you correctly, what you want is the first `<a>` tag to act as a `display:block` so that when you hover over it the entire width is clickable, but you want the second `<a>` tag to float to the right on the same line.

I believe that [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arwxh/) will accomplish what you wish. I changed the order of the anchor links to make it as easy as possible. Also added background colors so you could see what's going on.

```
<li class="file"><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a><a href="">Long Link Name</a>
```

The CSS required would be:

```
ul.tree li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.tree a {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    background-color: gold; //so you can see what's happening
}
ul.tree .delete {
    background-color: lightgreen; //so you can see what's happening
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
ul.tree a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue; //so you can see what's happening
}
.tree li.directory {
    background: url(/images/directory.png) left top no-repeat;
}
.tree li.file {
    background: url(/images/file.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

If changing the order of the anchors is out of the question, I could muck around with some more elaborate CSS, but as the complexity of the CSS increases, so do your chances of it breaking in one browser or the other.

---

**EDIT:** Based on your reply, I've created some CSS to add an ellipsis (…) when the link text is too long. It requires setting a width on the main `<ul>`, but from your initial question it sounds like you're doing that anyway. You can see the [updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arwxh/5/), and here's the updated CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 333px;
}
ul ul {
    width: inherit;
}
a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul.tree li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.tree a {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    background-color: gold; //so you can see what's happening
}
ul.tree .delete {
    background-color: lightgreen; //so you can see what's happening
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
ul.tree a:hover {
    background-color: lightblue; //so you can see what's happening
}
.tree li.directory {
    background: url(/images/directory.png) left top no-repeat;
}
.tree li.file {
    background: url(/images/file.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

[**Original Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arwxh/)  |  [**Fiddle with long links**](http://jsfiddle.net/Arwxh/5/)

Comment: Sorry for troubles with understanding my post. I'm not use to writing in english, so I still have troubles with putting my thoughts into words. I tried to write it detailed enought to understand, too bad I couldn't. But your answer is correct, it's exactly what I wanted to do. Still, there is one additional problem with too long filename, but I'll manage it somehow. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh! And I was *not* criticizing your English! I wish I could speak another language, let alone convey a question about **CODE** in it! You did fine!

Comment: Now it's done fully as I wanted to do. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 1):

Change the anchor tags to inline block and then float the second one to the right

```
ul.tree a {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.tree li a:last:child {
    float: right;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6a48W/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I was hoping for. Well, the view is correct, but the first `<a>` tag's area ends with the end of file name (between `<a>` and `</a>` tags). Area between first and second `<a>` is free and belongs only to parent `<li>`. And I need it to belong to first `<a>`, even if there is no such long text in, because this area is supposed to be used with first `<a>` tag's events.

Comment: Is this more like it? - [**http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4H3fr/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4H3fr/1/) Otherwise an image of what this is supposed to look like will be required.

Comment: Yes, it's more like this, but there is problem I also had before. Please, notice, that "delete" is one line below the correct `<li>` line. I didn't notice it at the begining, but your first answer also has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery Javascript ?

You could use the `append()` function to add the `<a>` tags specifically where you need them to appear.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

Answer (score 0):

Adding some `float` and `overflow` to css:

```
ul.tree li {
    ...
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
.delete {
    float: right;
}
.tree li a:first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9rxeu/

Comment: Thank you, but there is the same problem as in my first comment to Paulie_D.

Comment: Ah okay, missed that.